# Magento billing and shipping fields in register page

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to show billing and shipping fields in register page?

Comment: Bro possible nenga ena theme use panaringa

Comment: Rwd theme bro...

Comment: U want  to show `Address`, `Country`, `State`, ect.. right?

Comment: yes........pls help me to show bro...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Created an observer file of event `<customer_register_success>`

config.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Vendor_Moduel>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Vendor_Module>
        </modules>
        <frontend>
            <events>
                <customer_register_success> 
                    <observers>
                        <shipping>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>Vendor_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>shipping_field</method>
                        </shipping>
                    </observers>
                </customer_register_success>
            </events>
        </frontend>
    </config>
```

And the Observer file is

```
class <Vendor>_<Module>_Model_Observer extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
    public function shipping_field(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('create_shipping_address')){
            $shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
            $shippingAddressForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
            $shippingAddressForm->setFormCode('customer_register_address')->setEntity($shippingAddress);

            $shippingAddressData = array(
                    'firstname'  => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('firstname'),
                    'lastname'   => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('lastname'),
                    'company'    => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_company'),
                    'street'     => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_street'),
                    'city'       => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_city'),
                    'country_id' => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_country_id'),
                    'telephone'  => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('telephone'),
                    'region_id'  => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_region_id'),
                    'postcode'   => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_postcode')
                );

            $shippingAddressErrors = $shippingAddressForm->validateData($shippingAddressData);

            if($shippingAddressErrors === true){
                $shippingAddress->setId(null)
                                ->setIsDefaultBilling(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_default_billing', false))
                                ->setIsDefaultShipping(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_default_shipping', false));

                $shippingAddressForm->compactData($shippingAddressData);
                $customer = $this->_getCustomer();
                $customer->addAddress($shippingAddress);

                $shippingAddressErrors = $shippingAddress->validate();

                if (is_array($shippingAddressErrors)) {
                    $errors = array_merge($errors, $shippingAddressErrors);
                }
            }else{
                $errors = array_merge($errors, $shippingAddressErrors);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`register.phtml` file add below shipping fields

```
<div id="shipping_address_fields" class="fieldset">
                <input type="hidden" name="create_shipping_address" value="1" />
                <div class="form-top-title">
                    <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Shipping Address Information') ?></h2>
                </div>                          
                <div>
                    <ul class="form-list">
                        <li class="fields">
                            <div class="field" id="shipping_businessName">
                                <label for="shipping_company" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Company') ?> <em>*</em></label>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="shipping_company" id="shipping_company" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getShippingCompany()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Company') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="wide register-70">
                            <label for="shipping_street_1" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Road') ?> <em>*</em></label>
                            <div class="input-box" style="clear: both;">
                                <input type="text" name="shipping_street[]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getShippingStreet(1)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Road') ?>" id="shipping_street_1" class="input-text required-entry" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <?php for ($_i=2, $_n=$this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines(); $_i<=$_n; $_i++): ?>
                            <li class="wide register-30">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label for="street_1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('No') ?>.</label>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <input type="text" name="shipping_street[]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getShippingStreet($_i)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address %s', $_i) ?>" id="shipping_street_<?php echo $_i?>" class="input-text" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="field  register-40">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label for="shipping_zip" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Postcode') ?> <em>*</em></label>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <input type="text" name="shipping_postcode" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getShippingPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="shipping_zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international required-entry" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        <?php endfor ?>
                        <li class="fields register-60">
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="shipping_city" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Place') ?> <em>*</em></label>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <input type="text" name="shipping_city" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getShippingCity()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" id="shipping_city" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="field">
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="shipping_region_id" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('State') ?> <em>*</em></label>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <select id="shipping_region_id" name="shipping_region_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                                        <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                                    </select>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        //<![CDATA[
                                            $('shipping_region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue', "<?php echo $this->getFormData()->getShippingRegionId() ?>");
                                        //]]>
                                    </script>
                                    <input type="text" id="shipping_region" name="shipping_region" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text" style="display:none;" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="fields">
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="shipping_country" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?> <em>*</em></label>
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect(null, 'shipping_country_id', 'shipping_country_id') ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_default_billing"  value="0" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_default_shipping" value="1" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

and change the values of `default shipping address` hidden field from

```
 <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1"/>
```

To

```
 <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="0"/>
```

Comment: In magento 1, how can i get exact shipping state using observer? @Ranganathan

Answer (score 2):

**Step:1**

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
```

**Step:2**

Find

```
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

Just before add following line

```
<?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true) ?>
```

**Step:3**

This following change as like as below

```
<?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true) ?>

<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

> or

`/app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/layout/local.xml`

```
<customer_account_create>
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setData"><key>show_address_fields</key><value>1</value></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

Comment: ithu illa bro......Billing address show aguthu,,,,,shipping address fields add pani database la save pananum....

Comment: enoda or answer try pannunga athu correct one

Comment: bro nenga `CBE` enga irukinga and enga work panaringa

Comment: bro ungaluku 50 Reputation kuduthuruka

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/267985/ramesh-s intha link la chat panunga

Comment: Ganapathy la oru IT company la work panitrken broo

Comment: Na Annur Bro....

Comment: Evlo years experience neenga?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66706/discussion-between-ranganathan-s-and-ramesh-s).